# What are the English names of the Transformers supposed to be?

Tags: transformers-live-action-series

In the first *Transformers* live action movie, if I recall correctly, we hear that Transformers speak originally in a radio-noise-like language. But even if this wasn't the case and I misunderstood it, certain Transformers have names which clearly come from English, such as Bonecrusher or Barricade.

What are these English names supposed to be? Is it supposed Transformers just made them up when they arrived on Earth or something?

Comment: Why would you assume they aren't just translations into English of their existing names?

Comment: @Valorum what is a bone for a robot?

Comment: Transformers have bones; https://www.reddit.com/r/transformers/comments/m3nigg/do_transformers_have_bones_in_any_continuity/

Comment: @valorum ok, then, what was Megatron (which doesnt exist as English word) translated from?

Comment: "*Budiansky has said in interviews that it is a portmanteau of electronic and megaton.* - Presumably both words (or their equivalents) exist in Cybertronian